# How to display a random View?

Tags: iphone, random, view

I'm new to Objective-C.
I created several `SingleView`'s that display different content. I now need to create some code that will allow the user, when he presses the next button to get to a different, randomly picked, `View`. How can I do this?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Are you looking to display views which you created programmatically or load view controllers?

Comment: load view controllers, but in a random order!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have imported all your View Controllers.

```
#import "ViewController0.h"
#import "ViewController1.h"
#import "ViewController2.h"
```

and so on. Then use this code for your button:

```
-(IBAction)myButtonMethod:(id)sender {
NSInteger randomNumber = arc4random() % 3; // generates a random number between 0 and 2

switch (randomNumber) {
    case 0:
        ViewController0 *vc = [[ViewController0 alloc] init];
        [[self navigationController] pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
        break;
    case 1:
        ViewController1 *vc = [[ViewController1 alloc] init];
        [[self navigationController] pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
        break;
    case 2:
        ViewController2 *vc = [[ViewController2 alloc] init];
        [[self navigationController] pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

Modify the code to suit the number of VCs you want to include.

Answer (score 1):

Or, for fingers tired of typing:

```
NSArray *viewControllers = @[vc1, vc2, vc3];
UIViewController *randomViewController = viewControllers[arc4random_uniform(viewControllers.count)];
```